# Django Messages Framawork is not shown with index

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

Django Messages  Framawork is not shown with index.

The error message is displayed normally, however I need to get the status of the message before the array.

I tried using the index of the message array, but it did not display.

Would anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Thank you.

```
{% if messages %}
    <script>
        Swal.fire({
          type: {{ messages.0.tags }},  <-------- Is not shown
          title: 'Title',
          html:   '<ul class="messages" style="list-style: none;padding: 0;">\n' +
              '        {% for message in messages %}\n'+
                  '        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>\n'+
                  '            <div class="notification is-{% if message.tags == 'error' %}danger{% else %}success{% endif %}">\n'+
                  '                {{ message }}\n'+
                  '            </div>\n'+
                  '        </li>\n'+
                  '        {% endfor %}\n' +
              '    </ul>'
        })
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Check `messages.0` print anything or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the messages get "used" when you iterate of them one time you could construct the necessary JS variables in one loop before using them somehwere else:

```
var html = "";
{% for message in messages %}
  {% if forloop.first %}
  var type = message.tags;
  {% endif %}
  html += "<li>...html for one item</li>"
{% endfor %}
html = "<ul>" + html + "</ul>"
Swal.fire({
      type: type, 
      title: 'Title',
      html: html
})
```